# input text on postback returing NULL?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Can someone please tell me why the id of the checkbox 'userId' returns null on POST

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick='$("#userId").val("@user.Id"); return true; '/>

@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(Url.Action("Index", "ChangeUserAccount"), FormMethod.Post))
 {
   <input type="text" id="userId" />
   <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btnSubmit" value="Update" style="float:right;"  />
 }

[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult IndexPOST(UserLoginRecordIndexVM model, int? userId)
    {
```

So on screen the text box contains the correct ID of the checkbox, but when I click the 'Update' button NULL gets returned??

Comment: you didn't give the input a name. Without a name it won't get sent to the server.

Comment: what about trying `string userId`

Comment: excellent the name="userId" worked....cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="userId" name="userId" />
```

But, also make sure your action accepts it as a parameter, `string userId`, **or** that it's part of the model that's posted back. So, in your case you might just do this:

```
public ActionResult IndexPOST(UserLoginRecordIndexVM model, string userId)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you leverage this helper:

```
 @Html.TextBox("userId", null, new { id = "userId" });
```

This will add the appropriate `id` and `name` attributes to your textbox.